# How should I set Video Frame rate in open cv2

Tags: opencv

By default my camera reading 29 frame per second .but I want to reduce to 5 frame per second How will I do this???

```
import cv2

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('somevideo.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    print(count)
    count=count+1
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required sol of Given Problem

```
count = 0
videoFile = "Tom and jerry.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)   # capturing the video from the given path
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate
x=1
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameId = cap.get(1) #current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret != True):
        break
    if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
        filename ="frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cap.release()
print ("Done!")
```

Comment: Did you try `cap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,5)` ?

Comment: I tried with cap.set () but still it record 30 frame per second     ,cv2 latest version  does not accomodate with this one